# How is the size of a value without any size specification on instructions involving the stack determined?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

If we have an instruction, say `push 0`, how is the size of the operand specified if we don't add `word ptr` or `dword ptr` or something similar? It assembles without any errors, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on for what CPU you're compiling. If the architecture's word size is 32 bit, a 32 bit value will be pushed on the stack, and similarly for 16 bit architectures.

In MASM, e.g., if you specify `.286` or `.186` (both with a 16 bit data bus) a 16 bit `0` is pushed on the stack. But the `.386` directive will cause a 32 bit value to be pushed on the stack. For GNU as you may specify `.code32` or `.code16` to yield similar results.

Comment: Actually with MASM, it depends on the current segment's USE16 or USE32 attribute. The CPU directives (`.286`, `.386`, etc..) just affect whether segments get the USE16 or USE32 attribute by default.

Answer (score 1):

On an instruction like `push 0` you would never write anything like `word ptr` or `dword ptr` since those are meant to be used with memory access wheras `push 0` clearly is all about an immediate value!
Most assemblers however will allow you to write `push word 0` and `push dword 0` for explicite size specification.

Without a specific size tag it all depends on the current `USE` setting. If `USE16` is active the word size is implied and if `USE32` is active the dword size is implied.

These implied sizes apply to what is pushed on the stack *at runtime*. They don't say anything about how the instruction is actually encoded!
Your example value **0** will most probably get encoded with the (shorter) sign-extended-byte version of the `push` instruction.